# Chow group of a DVR

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I need a sanity check on the following: If $A$ is a DVR then $CH_0(A) = 0$.

The proof is simple. A 0-dimensional cycle is of the form $Z= n \cdot [s]$, where s is the closed point of $\operatorname{Spec} A$. Let $\pi$ be a uniformizer of $A$. Then

$div(\pi^n) = length_A(A/(\pi^n))\cdot [s] = n \cdot [s]$.

Hence $CH_0(A) = Z_0(A)/R_0(A) = 0$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a community-wiki answer in order to record the discussion from the comments so that this question may be marked as answered (once this post is upvoted or accepted).

> Yes, it is correct. - **Mohan**

I (KReiser) agree with Mohan's assessment as well. Your work is correct.